# TFS 2013 Change address in solution

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2013

TFS has this wonderful feature where if you connect to TFS and the project you are working on is not from that connection, it is closed and it tells you to clone.

I have a local TFS2013 on my machine. Due to some strange behaviour on the machine, I'm able to connect using 1 of 3 address

```
1. http://localhost:8080/tfs
2. http://127.0.0.1:8080/tfs
3. http://myMachineName/tfs
```

The issue if I am able to connect with `localhost` then the next time I connect with say `127.0.0.1`, I cannot work on the previous project with TFS. The solution closes and it asks me to clone the project again. If I'm able to connect to the previous address, then I can continue with my work.

It appears it see these 3 as different servers.

Is there a place I can change the TFS address for the solution to point to which ever one I'm able to connect to?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the sln file in a text editor (or you may be able to do it in VS by going File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control)

[image]

Comment: Just checked the sln file and I could not `GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl)`. Is it because I'm using TFS with GIT? Also my file menu does not have any item names 'Source Control'. If did however find `Views/Toolbars/Source Control - Team Foundation` but all the buttons have been greyed.